# MATLAB plot FIR magnitude given filter coefficients

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have an array with all the FIR filter coefficients `a_k`, now I need to plot the impulse response. I thought about using this code:
I have 61 coefficients

```
output = zeros(1,61); 
for k=1:61
   output = output + coeff(k) * dirac(61-k);
end
```

but the values in the vector `output` are all infinite. What's the problem?

Comment: The FIR coefficients _are_ the impulse response, right? So just use `stem(coeff)`, or perhaps `stem(coeff(end:-1:1))`. Anyway, `dirac` is the _continuous-time_ Dirac delta function. That's why it gives `inf` for input `0`

Comment: @LuisMendo stem actually plots only the imaginary component (if it exists anywhere in the vector), and otherwise it plots the real component. I would recommend using being explicit and plot stem(abs()) if you want the magnitude of the impulse response

Comment: @hiandbaii I am not sure I really follow you. How can you have a complex number impulse response (in time domain) ? In case you actually do have a complex output, would not `real` be the function to use then?

Comment: @patrik Complex impulse responses are fairly common. For example, a Rayleigh channel can be modeled as a time varying FIR filter (and it's going to end up having complex coefficients)

Comment: @hiandbaii This is of course true, but then we are talking application specific cases here. I guess that you have a point though, since `real` is not always correct. In case the signal is expected to be complex (eg. rayleigh fading channel) and the impulse response of received **signal power** is wanted, then `abs` is the way to go. This is however really application specific and you will not get the impulse response of the **signal** (may be negative). To get this, the components in a rayleigh fading channel must be separated and ploted separately. Then `abs` is not the right function.

Comment: @patrik You are correct patrik. The components would be need to be plotted separately in that case. You should only use abs() if you want the magnitude of the impulse response.